# Form all possible unique 3 digit number combinations from given elements in Python,

Tags: python, permutation

Consider a non-empty array **inarr** containing non-zero positive single digit integers, separated by ','

Print a string based on the following conditions:

1. Form all possible unique 3 digit number combinations with the elements of inarr
2. Identify the maximum number among the three-digit combinations formed
3. Print maximum number along with the total number of unique three-digit combinations formed, separating them with a ','.

**Assumption:** inarr contains at least 3 elements

**Note:** An element present at a particular index should not be considered more than once while forming a combination.

**Input:** Read inarr from standard input stream

**Explanation:** Sample Input `1,2,1,4` for the input inarr all possible unique 3 digit number combinations are: `121,411,124,214,114,142,141,211,421,112,241,412` The maximum number is `421` and total unique combinations are `12`, therefore output will be `421,12`

Comment: Show your attempt first.

Comment: @maciek97x I am unable to form 3 digit numbers, and therefore need help. I looked up permutations from itertools, but they are given in a tuple form and not in an integer or string form.

Comment: @shrekh And you don't know how to make a string out of a tuple? Hint: `str.join`

Comment: @Błotosmętek thank you I will try that

Comment: To remove duplicates you can use `perm = list(set(perm))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from itertools import permutations    

elements = list(input("").split(',')) #makes a list of the input elements,
                                      #splitting them at ','

p = permutations(elements, 3)         #stores all possible permutations in p

x = list(set(p))                      #set removes duplicates, stores a list in x

list = []

for i in x:                           #i iterates the elements in x, here a tuple
    p = ''.join(i)                    #join concatenates the strings inside tuple
    list.append(int(p))

list.sort()
print(str(list[-1])+','+str(len(list))) #prints the last element and length
```

Comment: @ItamarMushkin comments have been added

Answer (score 0):

JAVA :

```
import java.util.*;

class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String arr[] = s.split(",");
        int freq[] = new int[10];
        int count[] = new int[4];
        for(String a : arr){
            char c = a.charAt(0);
            freq[c-'0']++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(freq[i] == 0) continue;
            if(freq[i]>3) freq[i] = 3;
            switch(freq[i]){
                case 3:
                    count[3]++;
                case 2:
                    count[2]++;
                case 1:
                    count[1]++;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
        String a = "";
        for(int i = 9; i >=0; i--){
            if(a.length()==3) break;
            for(int j = 0; j < freq[i]; j++){
                if(a.length()==3) break;
                a = a + Integer.toString(i);
            }
        }
        int ans = count[3];
        ans += count[2] * (count[1]-1) * 3;
        ans += count[1] * (count[1]-1) * (count[1]-2);
        System.out.println(a+","+ans);
    }
}
```